# PN Diode connected in parallel with resistor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics, voltage

[image]

I just want to know that my logic is sound for the above question. 
So, since the diode is connected to a resistor in parallel, for the voltage values where V is less than the breakdown voltage, the resistor is the only contributor to the current I and thus the graph for the first part follows Ohm's law.

Once the V reached the breakdown voltage, however, the PN diode also starts contributing to the current, but since the resistor is still in play, there isn't the *steep* rise in current, characteristic of the diode, but it is enough to indicate a non-ohmic presence. Thus, the answer would be **A**.

Is that correct?

Comment: At each voltage $I_{\rm A}=I_{\rm C}+I_{\rm D}$ You are adding the currents which pass through each of the two components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, except one slight comment about reasoning post turn on voltage.   Just by elimination, C and D are wrong,  as they are the pure element IVs. If one considered the diode as a "perfect" element, it really would be a step function, limited only by the real series resistances elsewhere. The fact that diodes cannot physically do this means they are still a (very small) resistor post turn on, and open reverse and pre turn on.
 So in that case, you can approximate it as just the one resistor before turn on, then a tiny resistor in parallel with a large one post. Clearly most current would flow throw the smaller one, so that rejects B.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we know that:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{V}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)=\text{V}_{\space\text{D}}\left(t\right)=\text{V}_{\space\text{R}}\left(t\right)\\
\\
\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_{\space\text{D}}\left(t\right)+\text{I}_{\space\text{R}}\left(t\right)\\
\\
\text{I}_{\space\text{D}}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_{\space\text{S}}\cdot\left\{\exp\left(\frac{\text{V}_{\space\text{D}}\left(t\right)}{\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{k}\cdot\text{T}}{\text{q}}}\right)-1\right\}\\
\\
\text{V}_{\space\text{R}}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_{\space\text{R}}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}\\
\\
1<\text{n}<2\\
\\
\text{k}\approx1.3806485279\times10^{-23}\\
\\
\text{q}\approx1.602176620898\times10^{-19}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

So, we get:

$$\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_{\space\text{S}}\cdot\left\{\exp\left(\frac{\text{V}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)}{\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{k}\cdot\text{T}}{\text{q}}}\right)-1\right\}+\text{V}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)\cdot\frac{1}{\text{R}}\tag2$$

Where:

$$0.000086<\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{k}}{\text{q}}<0.00017\tag3$$

And when $\text{T}$ is room temperature we get:

$$19.7928<\frac{1}{\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{k}\cdot\text{T}}{\text{q}}}<39.5856\tag4$$

Comment: Uh, I didn't understand :/ What exactly is the conclusion you've come to?